# FFmpeg: m2ts -> MKV/AVI/MP4 w/ tri-audio and subtitles

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a 1080p m2ts file with three audio tracks and a subtitle track.
I'd like to convert it to a 720p MKV, or really *any format at all*, while retaining all three audio tracks along with the subtitle file.

Despite having three audio tracks, it shows up as having six, and two subtitle tracks.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '00003.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:24:53.39, start: 4198.958300, bitrate: 29700 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0.0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1100]: Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s32
    Stream #0.2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0.3[0x1101]: Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32
    Stream #0.4[0x1101]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.5[0x1102]: Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, mono, s32
    Stream #0.6[0x1102]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0.7[0x1200]: Subtitle: pgssub
    Stream #0.8[0x1201]: Subtitle: pgssub
```

Running this command outputs a 1280x720 video with a single audio track and no subtitles.

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -i 00003.m2ts -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -tune film -crf 22 -vf scale=-1:720 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Googling around clued me into the -map function, but selecting just the tracks I want to include renders an error.

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -i 00003.m2ts -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -tune film -crf 22 -vf scale=-1:720 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict experimental -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 -map 0:5 -map 0:7 -vn output.mp4
Number of stream maps must match number of output streams
```

Any advice I seem to find is completely useless due to changes to the syntax. For example, many guides use `c:v` and `a:v` instead of `-vcodec` and `-acodec`. I assume the version I have installed isn't too out of date. For the record I'm running Debian 7.

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 28 2014 17:50:37 with gcc 4.7.2
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

Update: Switching to the ffmpeg provided in the comments solved my issue.

Running the command below successfully outputs all three audio tracks and subtitle tracks.

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -i 00003.m2ts -vcodec libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryslow -tune film -scodec copy -acodec aac -b:a 192k -strict experimental -map 0:0 -map 0:5 -map 0:3 -map 0:1 -map 0:7 output.mkv
```

For those who stumble upon this while Googling, change the second number in the `-map` functions to select your tracks, and make sure to include `-scodec copy` when ripping subtitles. Edit the `-crf` number to change the amount of compression. Google it to learn more, and be sure to look up -tune as well, as there are many different types suitable to different kinds of video.

Comment: The version you have *is* a little outdated. In fact, it's not even the real "ffmpeg" from [the FFmpeg project](http://ffmpeg.org/). It's from the fork [Libav](http://libav.org/), from a time when they called their program `ffmpeg` instead of `avconv`. Download a recent version of the "original" here: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html — then please show us the full, uncut command line output, not just the parts you think are relevant. Thanks!

Comment: You have a `-vn` in your command, which disables video streams. Probably not what you want?

Comment: @slhck Thank you, switching to the "original" made everything behave the way I intended.